# Scaffolder issue in .NET Core 3

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I've been using the docs to scaffold the full identity but there are many issues.
when i create the scaffold with override all files and choosing the + for a new context class and user class, it generates this in IdentityHostingStartup and vbrings lots of problems with it:

```
builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
               services.AddDbContext<EF1Context>(options =>
                   options.UseSqlServer(
                       context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

               services.AddDefaultIdentity<EF1User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EF1Context>();
           });
```

IF i run it immidiately i get System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Identity.Application'

IF i comment below code as some suggest because of repetition i get InvalidOperationException: unable to resolve service for typeMicrosoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[EF1.Areas.Identity.Data.EF1User]' while attempting to activate 'EF1.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<EF1User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EF1Context>();
```

IF i change the ConfigureServices to below as the docs suggest get InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[EF1.Areas.Identity.Data.EF1User]' while attempting to activate 'EF1.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.
Still the EF1 user and context is not recognized.

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        // services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

What to do?